# How can I get the error that mongoose throws in the frontend? In order to display an specific message to the users. I'm using React with redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongoose, redux, backend

Im building a to-do list app just for practice. I have a "register" component in the frontend which I want to display a message when the email that the new user is trying to use is already taken.

When I try to register a new user with an already taken email, in the backend, mongoose displays a message on the terminal with the cause of the error. Code, key, etc.

In order for me to display an specific message, I need to get that message in the frontend.

In my controller (backend) Im using a trycatch. I tried sending the error to the front with a res.send() and res.json(). The thing is that when I use the res.send or res.json in the "catch" part, redux interprets that the action was fulfilled instead of rejected.

Here is my controller:

```
async create(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    try {

      const newItem = await this.repo.create(req.body);
      res.status(201);
      res.json(newItem);

    } catch (error) {

      next(error);
    }
  }
```

Here is my register method of my repository class(frontend):

```
  async register(newUser: UserNoId): Promise<User> {

    const response = await fetch(`${this.urlBase}/register`, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(newUser),
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    });

    const data = await response.json();
    return data;

  }
```

And here is my current slice:

```
export type UserState = {
  user: User | undefined;
  loginStatus: '' | 'logged' | 'loginerror' | 'loading';
  registerStatus: 'registered' | 'loading' | 'error' | '';
  token: string | undefined;
};

const initialState: UserState = {
  user: undefined,
  loginStatus: '',
  registerStatus: '',
  token: undefined,
};

const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'user',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    logout: (state) => {
      state.loginStatus = '';
      state.token = undefined;
      state.user = undefined;
    },
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(registerThunk.pending, (state) => {
      state.registerStatus = 'loading';
    });
    builder.addCase(registerThunk.fulfilled, (state) => {
      state.registerStatus = 'registered';
    });
    builder.addCase(registerThunk.rejected, (state) => {
      state.registerStatus = 'error';
    });
  },
```

Comment: Return an ***error*** response from the backend. This might include setting a specific error status code as well.